# Set spinner value by default in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner which I am creating dynamically from an activity.I want to select a value as per database from sever so I am doing this

```
         String[] items = { "Credit Card", "Cash"};

            final Spinner TP = new Spinner(this);
            TP.setId(20);
            TP.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            TP.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_bg);
            TourExpenseListDetailRow.addView(TP);// add the column to the table row here
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)TP.getLayoutParams();
            params1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
            TP.setLayoutParams(params1);

        //Selecting value as per database for testing I am selecting Position 1 
            TP.setSelection(1);

            ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, items);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            TP.setAdapter(aa);
```

**But My problem is my value is never get selected**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving

```
TP.setSelection(1);
```

after

```
TP.setAdapter(aa);
```

Also consider following Java naming conventions. Variable names should be mixed-case meaning they start with lower-case and subsequent words start with upper-case so

```
Spinner TP
```

would be

```
Spinner tp
```

or maybe

```
Spinner tP
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Something like this**

```
private void setUpSpinner() {
    //TODO: for the medical profile
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.demoArray,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    medicalProfile.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){
        case R.id.medicalProfile:
            String medicalStr = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.d("MedSpinner",medicalStr);
            break;

    }
}
```